# Template Haskell: how to rewrite this?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have this `pSizeOf` function which takes a type param and returns the size of that type as type-level literal:

```
import Foreign.Storable
import Language.Haskell.TH
import qualified Data.Kind as K

pSizeOf :: forall (t :: K.Type). (Storable t) => TypeQ
pSizeOf = pure $ LitT $ NumTyLit $ fromIntegral $ sizeOf (undefined :: t)
```

I wonder is it possible to rewrite it without using type param `t`, something of type

```
pSizeOf :: Name -> TypeQ
```

How can I get `undefined` of that type from `Name`? The following code:

```
pSizeOf :: Name -> TypeQ
pSizeOf n = pure $ LitT $ NumTyLit $ fromIntegral $ sizeOf $( SigE (VarE 'undefined) (ConT n))
```

fails with error:

```
    * GHC stage restriction:
        `n' is used in a top-level splice, quasi-quote, or annotation,
        and must be imported, not defined locally
    * In the untyped splice: $(SigE (VarE 'undefined) (ConT n))
```

Comment: You can't define a TH operation and use it in the same file, you need to make a separate module.

Comment: The stage restriction here applies to the local binding `n`, not to a top-level function, so moving the function to a different file won't help. The best you can do is to have a nested splice - something like `pSizeOf n = [| pure $ LitT $ NumTyLit $ fromIntegral $ sizeOf (undefined :: $(conT n)) |]`. Then you can write e.g. `type T = $($(pSizeOf ''Int))`